# value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName

Tags: scala, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks

I am trying to do this:

```
.withColumn("System", when($"SysID".split("-").length > 3, $"SysID".split("-").take(3)).otherwise(null))
```

But I get the following error:

error: value split is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.ColumnName

What can I do to use the split function?

Thank you.

Comment: Correction to the code above: `.withColumn("System", when($"SysID".split("-").length > 3, $"SysID".split("-").take(3).mkString("-")).otherwise(null))` but error still remains

Comment: what is SysID? Is that a column or a variable somewhere in the code?

Comment: SysID is a column name.

Comment: can you try ```col("SysID").split("-").length``` ?

Comment: I tried that. Same error.

Comment: another idea is to do ```split($"SysID", "-")```  (this would be the spark built in split function not the one defined on string)

Comment: I tried that too length(split($"SysID", "-")) but this time it fails at length. Also there is not take function for it.

Comment: I think it is ```size(split($"SysID", "-")) ``` not length

Comment: great. I will try that. How do I do a "take" after that though?

Comment: I switched to using map and was able to do all the manipulation I needed to do. sinanspd thanks for your help. You had the closest answers

Comment: Glad you got it and glad I could be of help. Sorry I didn't see your follow up question until now. I highly recommend answering your own question with the final solution that you accomplished so anyone who has this problem in the future doesn't have to dig through the comments. Cheers..

Answer (score 1):

split and length are a member of [org.apache.spark.sql.functions](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#split-org.apache.spark.sql.Column-java.lang.String-) 
so you can do : `when(length(split($"SysID", "-")) > 3)`

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
df.withColumn("System", when(length(col("SysID"))> 3, split(col("SysID"), "_")))
```